# If I define prefix_header_file in my Podspec for my local Framework project, what will it be applied to?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to break out some common code into a Framework project. Since I realized that my framework project will have dependencies of its own, I set up a Podspec for it. In my Framework project, I have a PCH file that I have set up in my target of the project.

The Cocoapods of the framework project finds my local pod, but I could not get the pch to be applied. I realized it was because it was cocoapods, not xcode that has to use my pch file... it seems cocoapods does not care about my "Prefix Header" project build setting.

I found the "prefix_header_file" podspec setting, and it seems to work. However, in the cocoapods documentation, it says

> The file path options is not recommended as Pods should not pollute the prefix header of other libraries or of the user project.

So I am wondering, what will happen when I build my app? What I want, is that when my Framework project is built and used by my other projects, the prefix headers in my PCH file are applied, but only for the headers in *my* local pod, not the others, like AFNetworking.

Comment: I suspect that comment is wrong since I believe the pch is only applied to the specific pod's Build Settings.

Comment: +1 to @PaulBeusterien. The only thing that bothers me and that kind of matches the above warning is that this "prefix_header_file" is applied to tests subspec/target as well - so that is the only "other party" which prefix gets "polluted".

Another thing that should be taken into the account is that this prefix should not be included into the framework/umbrella header - i.e. one should be careful to avoid podspec 'source_files' (or 'public_header_files') accidentally include the prefix among other headers and etc.